# Vuejs performance tuning - monitoring when my components are re-rendered

Tags: vue.js

I am developing a PWA in vue.js and I want to investigate when are my components re-rendering uselessly (my app is slow sometimes).

My first idea would be to add some `console.log` within the `mounted` and `beforeUpdate` hooks to see when they are re-rendering, but I have close to 100 components and this does not seem very efficient. Is there an easier way to monitor this? Or a default piece of code I can add to some hooks for all the components in my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off course you can set a general component containing your code in a certain hook and then all your components will extends the « basic one »

It’s called mixin.You’ll  find all what you need to know here :

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html